# Trouble connecting a laptop to a working router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wireless-router

If this is not the most appropiate forum please tell me where should I go.

I have a router model ch6643E that's been working for several months, with a laptop, several mobile phones and a TV connecting to it with no problem.

I bought a new laptop, and it gets continous disconnects when being on WiFi, both on the regular network and the so called "5G" that's available in my country (it is supposed to be stronger/get less interferences due to bandwith, I think), so anything that requires to load or buffer does not properly work (any video, any download gets interrupted).

After months of trying to fix it I figured it had to be the laptop so I gave it back, got my money, and bought a new one, different model just in case.

The issue persists, and I fail to find a reason for just the new laptops having connectivity issues, and not the rest of the devices.

Is there something I can do as a user to check with the router, or something I should configure, or a general problem with the router so I can make my company to pay me attention since so far nothing I have tried with my limited knowledge has worked (re-starting every device including the router, getting closer to the source, unpluging, as I said, googling for possible known bugs).

The laptop has windows 10 pre installed by whoever sold it, and when going to network settings, it says something like (I have to translate) "connected, NO internet, secure". I attach image in case anyone understands spanishenter image description here

[image: spanish for "connected, NO internet, secure"]

Thanks in advance and sorry to bother y'all.

Answer (score 1):

Try a different router.  The router you have is equipped with just the 2.4 GHz band and the laptop is not completely compatible with it.

You could also try a 2.4 GHz USB Wireless Card and that will very likely work for you.

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for your answer, it helped us when contacting the company to be able to get a new router, which they had refused previously. Second, currently the new model is "router model tc7230.O", but the problem persists. I am currently looking for compatibility between the laptop Wi-Fi protocols (802.11ac and 802.11ax) and the router, but I do not know enough about routers to do this properly.

Comment: Try a different Wireless card as suggested earlier.

Comment: Is it possible to swap a wireless card on a laptop? I will look around, thanks

Comment: USB Wireless Cards plug into a USP port. If can be installed and the on-board card disabled in Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates a problem with your router.

The error you are seeing means that the computer is connecting to the router OK, but the router is not providing a signal.  If I were not technically inclined I would be asking my ISP to update its firmware or replace it (as it looks to be an ISP supplied type of device, and the manual implies its fairly old - mentioning windows XP - Windows 8, but not Windows 10 - although that is not the problem).  It also appears to only support slow Internet speeds ( its Docsis 3.0 which dates back to 2006.  I've not used cable modems, but I expect your speeds are being limited by such old hardware).

I do note (as a tech person), you could leave the modem in place, get another Ethernet modem and install that between your computers and the existing router. There is a not of fiddling involved (disabling WIFI on the existing router and changing IP range of new router) - which would work around the problem, but you are still left with an outdated modem.

We can only speculate wildly what's causing the issues in your router. Its almost certainly a software issue.  It could be that the connection tracking table is overwhelmed with the number of devices, the DHCP range set aside is to small, the ARP table handling is faulty or there is a corruption related to the IP persistence database.

Comment: Hi, once again thank you for your detailed answer, thanks to this we contacted the company and got a new router. The new model is "router model tc7230.O", but the problem persists, even though it supports 802.11ac and 802.11ax  . Is there any configuration I could check or guide I could follow to make sure everything is in order? This is my friends second laptop in two months, and they are already looking for a new one, since neither have worked on their home... I don't think buying new laptops is going to fix the issue but am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This problem is quite weird - the problem should not be this hard to solve.  Can you provide a traceroute from a working and a not working device (dest 8.8.8.8 will do). Also, can you look in your router and provide the IP address and netmasks associated with both the LAN and WAN interfaces and details about the dhcp settings (I'm wondering if the problem relates to badly set up nat or if your device has to few IP addresses reserved for dhcp). I'm not at all confident of any of this though.

Answer (score 1):

According to the message it seems that you are connected to the router but you don't have internet. You said that you boughted from someone who had installed Windows 10 so did you check if he maybe config the wifi to a manual ip? That will cause no internet if the ip and dns are not correct. By the way 5G is the frequency 5Ghz and nothing to do with the mobile 5G that stands for 5th Generation. In that frequency you get a larger bandwidth but the signal gets a bit worse.